# how to select all contents and copy them of any tags with jquery / js

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to select all text that exists in my div.
and then how can copy? with jquery . or javasacript

i want to select my div tag content with my button when clicked.

```
<div id="yes">
    <!-- //long - content//-->
</div>
<input id="btn1" type="button">
<script>
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
       /*here i want to select my div content*/
    })
</script>
```

how can i select div content? and how can copy it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this code doesn't work in JQuery `click` handler, but without it works

```js
document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", function() {
    const range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(document.getElementById("yes"));
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
});
```